# WKWebView doesn't interact anymore with Javascript in iOS10

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have a native app which has to interact with a website. It has been working normally up to iOS 9, but with iOS 10, the Javascript code inside the web app is no longer valid.

Here is an example of the JS code I use on the onClick event of a button, which as mentioned worked like a charm before iOS10.

```
function DoSomething()
{
     var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
     var url='codeToBeUsed://id=1230';
     iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
     document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
     iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
     iframe = null;
}
```

when I debug the app on Xcode, the **request** variable which normally contained the content of the "url" variable on the example provided, now returns a blank value...

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x170011070> { URL: about:blank }
```

I even tested placing a **alert('click');** but it didn't work either. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a code close to yours (I pass a stringified json in the src), I also got an embarassing 'about;blank' in the request.

It seems iOs10 has some new restrictions on what you pass to iframe 'src'. I found it requires a valid url to trigger properly the request.

Try to use :

```
var url='codeToBeUsed://?id=1230';
```

Edit : or encode URI...